# Rebuilding Variable at a Different Base (R)

Tags: r

I am trying to rebuild this variable using the % changes at a different base. I want the base to start at 5, using the percent changes in colunmn 2, is there a way to build the variable without using a loop?

I am using this code below in R with little success:

```
    data$intial=lag(data$intial,-1)*(data$pctchng)
       Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE

    ratio     pctchng    initial
1.005028571 NA            5
1.006367978 0.133270514   NA
1.00566508  -0.069845001  NA
1.010365029 0.467347325   NA
1.013941983 0.354025918   NA
1.007602862 -0.625195643  NA
1.004898686 -0.268377165  NA
1.005610413 0.070825714   NA
1.00494049  -0.066618579  NA
1.007815989 0.286136319   NA
```

Comment: I think we need more info. How do you want your result to look like? Also, you have a typo in your command ( initial != intial ).

Comment: You probably wanted a positive lag, since that means 'earlier'. This would overwrite the first value of "initial" so it seams that self-referential lags aren't really the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
> cumprod(c(5, tail(data$pctchng, -1) + 1))

## [1]  5.000000  5.666353  5.270586  7.733781 10.471739  3.924854  2.871512
## [8]  3.074889  2.870045  3.691269
```

or

```
> cumprod(c(5, tail(data$pctchng, -1)/100 + 1))
## [1] 5.000000 5.006664 5.003167 5.026549 5.044344 5.012807 4.999354 5.002895
## [9] 4.999562 5.013867
```

which gives the same answer as vaettchen. depends on how you're defining pctchng

Answer (score 1):

Does that produce the result you mean:

```
data$idx <- data$ratio / data$ratio[ 1 ]
data$initial <- data$idx * 5

data
      ratio     pctchng  initial       idx
1  1.005029          NA 5.000000 1.0000000
2  1.006368  0.13327051 5.006664 1.0013327
3  1.005665 -0.06984500 5.003167 1.0006333
4  1.010365  0.46734732 5.026549 1.0053098
5  1.013942  0.35402592 5.044344 1.0088688
6  1.007603 -0.62519564 5.012807 1.0025614
7  1.004899 -0.26837716 4.999354 0.9998708
8  1.005610  0.07082571 5.002895 1.0005789
9  1.004940 -0.06661858 4.999562 0.9999124
10 1.007816  0.28613632 5.013867 1.0027735
```